# Error message when storing output from loop in matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix, storing-data

I have this program which calculates the realized covariance for each day in my sample but I have some troubles with storing the output in a matrix.

the program is as follows:

```
 for i=1:66:(2071*66)

vec = realized_covariance(datapa(i:i+65),data(i:i+65),datapo(i:i+65),data(i:i+65),'wall','Fixed',fixedInterval,5)

mat(2,4142) = vec

end
```

Output:

```
vec =

   1.0e-03 *

    0.1353   -0.0283
   -0.0283    0.0185
```

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

I have tried various way to store the output in a matrix like defining a matrix on zeroes to store the output in or let the row dimension of the storing matrix be undefined, but nothing seems to do the job.

I would really appreciate an advice on how to tackle this challenge.

Comment: You may please just delete the old question.

Comment: `realized_covariance` is not a native MATLAB function. Please share the code of that function so we can try to help you.

Comment: Hi all of you
I didn't know that this question was asked before?
As it didn't poped up when I searched for it.
To Adrian:
I can easily post the code for the realized covariance computation but it's not here I have problems.
If I just run the program without wanting to store the outputs in a matrix, it runs perfectly

Comment: @KristianNielsen: there's [186 questions with that exact error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5D+Subscripted+assignment+dimension+mismatch.) within the MATLAB tag on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I deeply apologizes I should have thought about searching on the error message, I was to fast to just post my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a solution which does the job.

I defined a matrix and then filled in all my output one at the time using the following:

```
A = zeros(0,0) %before loop, only serve to define the storing matrix

A = [A; vec]%after the calculating function, inside the loop.
```

Comment: This is also a solution. Good for you, for finding it yourself! Note that a good practice is pre-allocate the matrix before the loop (Like in @Adriaan's and mine answers) because increasing it on each iteration is time and memory consuming.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know Adiel.
I actually tried that but when I did that, I ended up with my my output been loaded to A at the last defined row.
e.g I began with defined A as  A = zeros(2071,2) and then the same as above, but then I ended up with my output beginning from the 2071'th row.
Where did i mess up?

Comment: The problem is that you take `A` as is, and add to it another data. so it takes all the zeros and add `vec` after that. In my answer I defined exactly where in the matrix the data should go.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to store a `2 x 2` matrix into a single element. I.e. 4 elements on the right hand side, one on the left. That won't fit. See it like this: you have a garage besides your house where 1 car fits. You've got three friends coming over and they also want to park their car inside. That's a problem though, as you've got only space for one. So you have to buy a bigger garage: assign 4 elements on the left (e.g. `mat(ii:ii+1,jj:jj+1) = [1 2;3 4]`), or use a cell/structure array.

As [Steve suggests in a comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035112/error-message-when-storing-output-from-loop-in-matrix/36035690?noredirect=1#comment59727337_36035690), you can use a 3D matrix quite easily:

```
counters = 1:66:(2071*66);
mat = zeros(2,2,numel(counters)); %// initialise output matrix
for ii=1:numel(counters)
    vec = realized_covariance(datapa(counters(ii):counters(ii+65)),...
    data(counters(ii):counters(ii+65)),datapo(counters(ii):counters(ii+65)),...
    data(counters(ii):counters(ii+65)),'wall','Fixed',fixedInterval,5)
    mat(:,:,ii) = vec; %// store in a 3D matrix
end
```

Now `mat` is 3D, with the first two coordinates being your regular output, i.e.e `vec`, and the last index is the iteration number. So to access the output of iteration `1032` you'd do `mat(:,:,1032)`, possibly with a [`squeeze`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) around that to make it 2D instead of 3D.

Comment: I'm a little unsure how to implement this Adriaan or more correctly i'm unsure how get the matrix growing as the loop produces output.
Thanks for your reply

Comment: For me it would be very natural to use the following matrix; mat(:,1:2) since it's a nx2 matrix as far as I have understood and then allocate each output in it.
But it doesn't seems to be correct.

Comment: @KristianNielsen Maybe consider a `2-by-2-by-N` matrix, e.g. `mat=zeros(2,2,2071)` then if `vec` is `2-by-2`, can store it as `mat(:,:,day_number)=vec`.

Comment: Hey Steve
Then I would have to define day_number right?
f.x. day_number = 1
and then include it in my loop?
to end up with something like: mat(:,:,day_number) = vec
And finish with: day_number = day_number + 1
or am I wrong?

Comment: @Adriaan `ii` is not a good counter for indexing the 3rd dimension of `mat`, because it's not continuous.

Comment: Hi Adriaan
I just tried for fun to implement your solution but I got the following message error; "TIME2 must be sorted and increasing".
So I look a little in to the elements of the program you provided me with above.
First of all, shouldn't it be: data(counters(ii):counters(ii+1) indstead of data(counters(ii):counters(ii+65) since you have arranged it as days and not individual observations?
Because when I do i like that, using data(counters(ii):counters(ii+1), I get exactly the data for one day. So this should solve the above error message, but unfortunately it does not.

Comment: @KristianNielsen since you do not provide me with `TIME2` I have no idea where your error creeps up.

Comment: I could easily provide you with but how do I share the data with you?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `mat(2,4142)` is a single location in a matrix, you can't assign there four values. 
You need to define the exact location inside `mat` every time you want to assign values into it. Try doing it like that:

```
mat=zeros(2,2142);
for k=1:66:(2071*66)
  vec=realized_covariance(datapa(i:i+65),data(i:i+65),datapo(i:i+65),data(i:i+65),'wall','Fixed',fixedInterval,5)
  mat(:,[(((k-1)/66)*2)+1 (((k-1)/66)*2)+2])=vec;

end
```

Comment: Hi Adiel

Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I still get the same error message.
The realized_covariance function produces a 2x2 matrix and I need to end up with a 4142x2 matrix containing all produced output during the loop.

Comment: @KristianNielsen You right, I edited it. Hope it'll work now!